# How do I disable zooming on iframe

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, viewport

I am embedding a webpage on my WordPress site with iframe
On the embedded webpage users write some text on the textareas,
the issue is;
when I click on the textarea on iframe, it zooms and my device becomes pretty much unresponsive. I am using chrome on Samsung S21.

I did try the viewport trick,

it did not work.

Hope someone answers my question.

Rei

Comment: Would you be able to reproduce this with an example? Or what causes the zoom? I don't think that is default behavior. Something in your site is triggering this, no?

Comment: Did this not work? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.